# Переменные в cmd командах

Tags: cmd, bat

Почему возникает ошибка при исполнении такого когда?

```
set AdmGroupSID=S-1-5-32-544 && set AdmGroup= && For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims==" %I In (`WMIC Group Where "SID = '%AdmGroupSID%'" Get Name /Value ^| Find "="`) Do set AdmGroup=%J && set AdmGroup=%AdmGroup:~0,-1%
```

В ответе

```
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Но если выполнять команды по одной проблемы нет.

```
set AdmGroupSID=S-1-5-32-544
set AdmGroup=
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims==" %I In (`WMIC Group Where "SID = '%AdmGroupSID%'" Get Name /Value ^| Find "="`) Do set AdmGroup=%J
set AdmGroup=%AdmGroup:~0,-1%
```

Код должен выполняться в одну строку, потому что отправляется на выполнение из php скрипта командой exec

Comment: Я понял, что нужно найти название встроенной локальной группы администраторов. А поскольку оно имеет жестко вшитый SID, то нет смысла городить несколько команд, задавая в переменной это значение. А не работает, потому что не только командный интерпретатор разбирает входную строку, но и утилита WMIC пытается использовать входные данные (заданные в переменной %AdmGroupSID%) как маску, а не как статичное заданное значение.

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем пихать значение (имя группы админов) в переменную окружения AdmGroup. Может лучше отдать её в php ?